# How to implement multiple fullscreen overlays in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm pretty new to web development and I'm trying to create a series of buttons that, when clicked, triggers an overlay specific to that button. The following code from [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_overlay.asp) creates a button and the overlay effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="overlay" onclick="off()">
  <div id="text">Text 1</div>
</div>

<div style="padding:20px">
  <h2>Overlay with Text</h2>
  <button onclick="on()">Button 1</button>
</div>

<script>
function on() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

How can I modify this code to add another button that, when clicked, displays `<div id="text">Text 2</div>` within the overlay? So, when Button 1 is clicked, "Text 1" is displayed within the overlay and when Button 2 is clicked, "Text 2" is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way you can do this is by giving your overlays classes with which you can select them from JavaScript. Give each overlay a unique id to identify it with.

```
<div class="overlay js-overlay" id="overlay-one" hidden>
  ...
</div>
```

Now you buttons should also have a class to identify them with. Give your button a `value` attribute in which you set the `id` of the overlay that the button belongs to.

```
<button class="js-overlay-trigger" type="button" value="overlay-one">Open overlay</button>
```

Now in JavaScript. Select all buttons with [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Loop over each button and add an event listener to it. This is (almost) the same as an `onclick` attribute, but you gives you much more flexibility and imo should be used in favor of the inline attribute.

Create a function that reads the `value` of the clicked button, this contains the `id` of the overlay we need. Select the element from the document based on the value in the `value` property. If the overlay is found, then the overlay will be shown.

```
const triggers = document.querySelectorAll('.js-overlay-trigger');

function showOverlay(event) {
  const selector = event.target.value;
  const overlay = document.getElementById(selector);
  if (overlay !== null) {
    overlay.hidden = false;
  }
}

for (const trigger of triggers) {
  trigger.addEventListener('click', showOverlay);
}
```

This example uses the `hidden` attribute and property to show overlay. But you can also add or remove CSS classes to get the same behavior. The `style` property should be used as a last resort.

### Edit

The closing of the overlays is done almost in the same manner. First you select all the overlays. Loop over each overlay and attach an event listener. The function attached to the event should hide the currently clicked overlay.

```js
const overlays = document.querySelectorAll('.js-overlay');

function closeOverlay(event) {
  const overlay = event.currentTarget;
  overlay.hidden = true;
}

for (const overlay of overlays) {
  overlay.addEventListener('click', closeOverlay);
}
```

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get the hidden attribute to work as it should so I opted for the style property and everything worked like a charm.

One question though - how can I modify JS to close the overlay with a click?

Comment: For the `hidden` attribute to work you would still need to write some CSS, for example `.overlay[hidden] { display: none }` This uses an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to get the overlay with the `hidden` attribute. I've added a new snippet in which the overlays are closed. In a lot of ways it's similar to how we did the triggers.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I didn't think about using event.currentTarget. It works perfectly!